# calculate area between four curves using matlab

Tags: matlab, area

### calculate area between four curves using matlab

Hi everyone,
I have four curves in matlab. The two of them are calculated through the following formulas
y=x and
y=1-x
The other two curves are calculated through a number (13) of values.
All of them shaped an area with their intersection points (ABCD) that I want to calculate.
I have to use trapz and if yes how?

and a second question. How can I fill in with a new color the spesific area (ABCD)?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Are you working in the xy plane?

How about doing 
[r,c]=find(y1==y2); among every 2 curves?

Comment: Thanks for the intant respone. Actually I want to calculate the area between these  intersection points and not the intersection points. And also there is one problem that this command deasnot work the matrix dimensions are not the same. The two curves have 13 values in their matrix while the other two have more.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried integrating the difference of the 2 functions between the certain boundaries given by ur 2 other values?

Area between the functions y1 = x and y2 = 1-x is going to be an integral of 1-2x or 2x-1 which is going to be the same area in absolute value.
Use this if you are integrating between 2 curves and 2 boundaries:

```
A = integral(function,xmin,xmax);
```

To interate between four curves y1 y2 x1 x2, use something like a double integral.
Function is the absolute difference between y1 and y2, and xmin/xmax are your function boundaries x1 and x2 depending on how you want them, and ymin/ymax are your boundaries for the y axis.

```
A = integral2(function,xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax);
```